# Date Picker Option Showing Blank List

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am using Angular 1.5.6 and I have a date picker but it is showing me blank screen when i click on the Month or year tab. as per screen shot below

[image]

Below is the html code.

```
<md-select md-no-float
    fix-md-select
    md-container-class="md-date-range-picker__select"
    ng-model="activeYear"
    placeholder="Year"
    class="md-no-underline">
<md-option class="custom-md-option"
    ng-value="year.id"
    ng-click="setActiveYear('activeMonth', year)"
    ng-bind="::year.name"
    ng-repeat="year in years">
     </md-option>
</md-select>
```

Localization Function

```
  function getLocalizationVal(val) {
        return ($scope.localizationMap !== null
            && $scope.localizationMap[val] !== null) ?
            $scope.localizationMap[val] : val;
    }
```

Thank you for seeing this.

Comment: Please post you JS code (where you define years / months)

Comment: Since you're using Angular material why not just use md-datepicker?

Comment: @Sébastien the issue was with getLocalizationVal function. Apparently when i removed the type check '=' from the statement it started working. If you know the reason for that write an Answer and I will mark it as correct :). Thank you